# mvn clean install intellij - compile error - can not find symbol

Tags: java, maven, apache-camel

From Intellij Idea Using Build menu , projects compiles succesfully,
but when we compiling using **"`mvn clean install`"** command it fails. What can be reason for this?
[image]

**Project Location:**
[image]

And I added these libraries for success compile in intellij using
**Project Structure->Libraries->New Project Library->Java**

[image]

**And this is how pom.xml looks**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.datastech.idmb.iba</groupId>
    <artifactId>idmb-test</artifactId>
    <version>3.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <description>IDMB TEST module</description>


    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <maven.build.timestamp.format>yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm</maven.build.timestamp.format>

        <datas-spring.version>1.2-SNAPSHOT</datas-spring.version>

        <!-- WEB -->
        <javax.servlet-api.version>3.1.0</javax.servlet-api.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>



        <!-- WEB -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>${javax.servlet-api.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <forceJavacCompilerUse>true</forceJavacCompilerUse>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addDefaultSpecificationEntries>true</addDefaultSpecificationEntries>
                            <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.8.2</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Comment: Are you in the same path as in IntelliJ when you fire `mvn clean install`?

Comment: yes, project location is "C:\BBSRC\IDMB\IDMB_SOURCE_CODE - Test\idmb-test" and I opened command windows here

Comment: Have you explicitly added jar to build path in intelliJ which is not present in pom.xml?

Comment: Yes , I added more jars using intellij and they are not present in pom.xml

Comment: I added libraries using :

Comment: Project Structure->Libraries->New Project Library->Java  @dkb

Comment: If all those jars are required, then you need to add those in pom.xml as dependencies too, add that and try `$mvn clean install` then this should work

Comment: can you help me how to add these jar to pom.xml? are there exists specific mvn command ? @dkb

Comment: [Maven - Introduction to the Dependency Mechanism](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Management)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get dependencies pom syntax from https://mvnrepository.com/
add in pom.xml as follows
Remember to add suitable version in following `<version>` tag

```
 <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.10.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-beans -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.10.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.0</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.0</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.0</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.mjeanroy/dbunit-plus -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.mjeanroy</groupId>
    <artifactId>dbunit-plus</artifactId>
    <version>0.2.0</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.fcrepo.camel/fcrepo-camel -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.fcrepo.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>fcrepo-camel</artifactId>
    <version>4.4.0</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.dbunit/dbunit -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.dbunit</groupId>
    <artifactId>dbunit</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.8</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.12</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
 </dependencies>
```

Comment: And how I can add external jars to pom.xml which is doesn't exists on mvnrepository? can you add example for external?

Comment: which one is not present?, can you add url from where you got jars for those dependencies?

Comment: I get it from email, this jar writed by some developer

Comment: Okay, checking from your image, get mjeanroy from : https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.mjeanroy

Comment: I mean datas-common-... jars

Comment: try adding this and check `<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-commons -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
    <version>1.10.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
`

Comment: Dear friend, I must use following jar,C:\BBSRC\IDMB\IDMB_LIBS\IDMB_LIBS\datas-dto-banking-1.3-SNAPSHOT.jar , How I must add this to pom.xml?

Comment: nice, that's the way we solve the problem, good finding: http://roufid.com/3-ways-to-add-local-jar-to-maven-project/